# General Data understanding

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm having major problems understanding the general data format of highstock. I saw the part of the documentation where it looks like this:

```
 data: [[5, 2], [6, 3], [8, 2]]
```

Now I am trying to get it to work. 
in the jsfiddle I am having 2 ways of data input.

Why does this work

```
[1336168800000, 15]
```

but this gets errors

```
 var CheckinData = new Array();
 CheckinData.push(new Array(1336168800000, 15));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3uWPz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a stray `],` in your jsfiddle code after the commented out series data.

See this version that works: http://jsfiddle.net/3uWPz/1/

BTW, you can more succinctly code this using a style of:

```
var CheckinData = [];
CheckinData.push([1336168800000, 15]);
```